# Ubuntu упал и не встаёт

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Всем привет!
Обращаюсь к вам за помощью.
Я являюсь счастливым обладателем asus x550c. По роду профессии я веб-разработчик и использую на ubuntu.
Некоторые время я использовал версию 18.4 совсем недавно (дня три) обновился до 19.10.
И в общем все работало хорошо. До тех пор, пока не случилось что то странное. 
В ходе работы я стал замечать что с панели "избранное" стали пропадать иконки приложений о.О Сначала пропала одна и я не предал этому значения, но через 15 минут из стало уже 3 из 7. Я поступил как программист... Перезапустил ОС.
Но это не помогло. Пришла беда.
Ubuntu запускается до этого момента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вывожу пароль и дальше упираюсь в такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если во время ввода пароля (первое фото) я жёстко выключу пк (отключу шнур питания) то при следующей загрузке получу следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда три пути...
При выборе system setup меня выбрасывает в  Биос. 
При выборе Ubuntu я снова вижу это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И после ввода пароля запускается терминал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытки поднять графическую оболочку с помощью 
startx
Закончились следующим

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе же пункта Advanced options for Ubuntu вижу следующие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе 1 и у пунктов я получаю тот же сценарий, что и при выборе Ubuntu в предыдущем меня
При выборе пунктов 2 и 4 вижу следующие.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s. Если у кого то есть знание и время мне помочь: nikell28 (Telegram)

Comment: Залогиньтесь в консоль и скажите `touch ~/.xsession` для начала. Потом попробуйте перезагрузиться и скажите что получилось.

Comment: Oxyd, ничего не выдает. Пустой файл. Есть файл ~/.xsession-errors содержание файла. 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QYci8_1qrRSLCqYbFZcPuBMwTofns56d/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Да, ~/.xsession и будет пустым, после команды touch, а вот после перезагрузки, есть шанс что Display manager его правильно заполнит.

Comment: @Oxyd, не вышло, всё так же

Comment: При установке ты жал галку "зашифровать домашний каталог"?

Comment: @donRumata, да. Это было сделано ради интереса, а потомо не смог убрать((

Comment: Я бы вытащил нужное файло и переставил бы с чиста. И без шифрования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась переустановкой gnome-shell 
Но причина падания это тема одельного вопроса

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ решением, что-б не висело.